# Cognito make username an email google auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

How do I make my cognito user pool username an email with google identity provider.

It is very confusing as well. In attribute mappings it says that google sub is username, but username has a format of "Google_randomnumber"

Please help me how do I assign my own username when doing google auth with cognito user pools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want the real name, you need to join given name and family name. The user name, you need to add an attribute it's Google username.

[image]

This is what looks like when you click the User in Users and Groups:

[image]

Comment: I wanted my USERNAME to be the email. See your email there? I want that to be username, so I can fetch that user with his email and I don't have to use that weird generated USERNAME (e.g  GOOGLE_googleIdNumber)

Comment: I don't think you can change that. That's part of the google Identity. That's my opinion. You can fetch the user and grab all the attributes including email with these settings.

Comment: Ended up doing that.. :(